# Android -> webview not showing correctly

Tags: android, webview, httpclient, html

There is one webpage (http://m.bonbon.hr/profile). When I log in from a web browser to that webpage I get screen like this (picture 1):

[image: Picture 1]

After few second this part where it says loading becomes this (picture 2):

[image: Picture 2]

Everything loads, and works perfect. Now my problem lies in my android app. I have HttpClient that sends data to that webpage, and gets a response (html code). Then i loaded that response to the webview in my app, but al I get is this( picture 3):

[image: Picture 3]

webview stuck at this loading, and it never changes. So i wonder how to make this happen, so that webview shows me webpage with all data like browser on Picture 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the webpage itself is using jquery or some other library that is being loading when opening it in a browser or webview.

If you only load the response which is pure html, you are most likely not loading additional CSS and maybe other libraries/frameworks like jquery.

Have a look at that webpages source coude and check the header what is getting included. You might have to add that to your html response then somehow.